# can I get help in solving this equation using simplex method big-M method

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Objective:

$\max Z= 100x_1+300x_2+400x_3$

s.t.   $10x_1+20x_2+30x_3≤1600$

$\;\,\quad10x_1+15x_2+20x_3≤1500$

$\;\,\quad x_2+x_3≤50$

$\;\,\quad x_1+x_2+x_3=70$

$\;\,\quad x_1,x_2,x_3≥0$

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i don not how to simplex this equation usig M - method ? can you help me to solve this equation ?

Comment: It might be good if you edit the question to read something like "Let $Z= \ldots$. What is the maximal value of $Z$ given the following constraints on $x_1, x_2$ and $x_3$ $\ldots$".

Answer (score 2):

$\max Z= 100x_1+300x_2+400x_3$

s.t.   $10x_1+20x_2+30x_3≤1600$

$\;\,\quad10x_1+15x_2+20x_3≤1500$

$\;\,\quad x_2+x_3≤50$

$\;\,\quad x_1+x_2+x_3=70$

$\;\,\quad x_1,x_2,x_3≥0$

You have to convert it into the standard form by adding slack variables. So it becomes:
$\max Z= 100x_1+300x_2+400x_3$

s.t.   $10x_1+20x_2+30x_3 +s_1 = 600$

$\;\,\quad10x_1+15x_2+20x_3 +s_2 =1500$

$\;\,\quad x_2+x_3+s_3=50$

$\;\,\quad x_1+x_2+x_3=70$

$\;\,\quad x_1,x_2,x_3,s_1,s_2,s_3≥0$

$c^T=[100, 300, 400, 0, 0, 0], b=[1600, 1500, 50, 70]$

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
10 & 20 & 30 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 
10 & 15 & 20 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 
0  & 1  & 1  & 0 & 0 & 1\\ 
1  & 1  & 1  & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$
The basics columns are these that construct the identity matrix, the columns $4,5,6$ of the matrix $A$, are the three first columns of the identity matrix $I_{4 \times 4}$. So you have to add the last column:
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
10 & 20 & 30 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
10 & 15 & 20 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 
0  & 1  & 1  & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 
1  & 1  & 1  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$
So $c^T=[100, 300, 400, 0, 0, 0, M], b=[1600, 1500, 50, 70]$

Base: $B=[P_4 P_5 P_6 P_7]$

The tableau is:

$$\begin{matrix}
B & c_B & b & P_1 & P_2 & P_3 & P_4 & P_5 & P_6 & P_7 & \Theta \\ 
P_4 & 0 & 1600 & 10 & 20 &30 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1600}{30} & L_1\\ 
P_5 & 0 & 1500 & 10 & 15 & 20 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1500}{20} & L_2\\ 
P_6 & 0 & 50 &  0& 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 50 & L_3\\ 
P_7 & M & 70 &  1& 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 70 & L_4\\
    & z & 70M &M-100 & M-300 & M-400 & 0 & 0 & 0&0 & & L_5
\end{matrix}$$

$M$ is a negative number.

To complete the column $\Theta$: you have to find the smallest number of the line $z$. Let $P_i$ is the column which number at the last line is the smallest, and then $\Theta=\frac{b}{P_i}$.

The smallest number at the last line is: $M-400$, so $\Theta=\frac{b}{P_3}$

The smallest number at the column $\Theta$ is $50$. So the smallest number of the last line($z$) is the column $P_3$ and the smallest number of the column $\Theta$ is the line $L_3$ that correspond to the line $P_6$, so the column $P_6$ gets out of the base and the column $P_3$ gets in.

The pivot is the element at the column $P_3$ and at the line $L_3$

So $L_3'=L_3/1$, $L_1'=L_1-30 L_3'$, $L_2'=L_2-20 L_3'$, $L_4'=L_4-L_3'$

$\begin{matrix}
B   & c_B & b & P_1 & P_2 & P_3 & P_4 & P_5 & P_6 & P_7 & \Theta \\ 
P_4 & 0   &100&  10 & -10  & 0   & 1 & 0   & -30 & 0   &         &L_1'\\ 
P_5 & 0   &500&10   &-5   & 0   & 0 & 1   &-20  &0    &         &L_2'\\ 
P_3 & 400 & 50& 0   & 1   &  1  & 0  & 0   &  1  &  0  &         &L_3'\\ 
P_7 & M   & 20&1    & 0   & 0   &0  & 0   & -1  &  1  &         &L_4'\\
    & z   & 400 \cdot 50+M \cdot 20 &  M-100   &  400-300   &  400-400   &0     &0     &400-M     & M-M    &         &L_5'
\end{matrix}$

So it becomes:
$$\begin{matrix}
B   & c_B & b & P_1 & P_2 & P_3 & P_4 & P_5 & P_6 & P_7 & \Theta \\ 
P_4 & 0   &100&  10 & -10  & 0   & 1 & 0   & -30 & 0   &   10      &L_1'\\ 
P_5 & 0   &500&10   &-5   & 0   & 0 & 1   &-20  &0    &   50      &L_2'\\ 
P_3 & 400 & 50& 0   & 1   &  1  & 0   & 0   &  1  &  0  &   -      &L_3'\\ 
P_7 & M   & 20&1    & 0   & 0   &0   & 0   & -1  &  1  &   20      &L_4'\\
    & z   & 20000+20M  &  M-100   &  100   &  0   &0    &0     &400-M     & 0    &         &L_5'
\end{matrix}$$

(The smallest number at the last line is $M-100$, so $\Theta=\frac{b}{P_1}$)
The smallest number at the column $\Theta$ is $10$ that corresponds to $P_4$, so the column $P_4$ gets out of the base and the base $P_1$ gets in.

$L_1''=L_1'/10$, $L_2''=L_2'-10L_1''$, $L_3''=L_3'$, $L_4''=L_4'-L_1''$

So the tableau is:
$$\begin{matrix}
B   & c_B & b & P_1 & P_2 & P_3 & P_4 & P_5 & P_6 & P_7 & \Theta=\frac{b}{P_6} \\ 
P_1 & 100   &10&  1 & -1  & 0   & 1/10 & 0   & -3 & 0   &   -&L_1''\\ 
P_5 & 0   &400&0   &5   & 0   & -1 & 1   &10  &0    &   40      &L_2''\\ 
P_3 & 400 & 50& 0   & 1   &  1  & 0   & 0   &  1  &  0  &   50      &L_3''\\ 
P_7 & M   & 10&0   & 1   & 0   &-1/10   & 0   & 2  &  1  &   5      &L_4''\\
    & z   & 21000+10M  &  0   &  M   &  0   &10-\frac{M}{10}    &0     &100+2M    & 0    &         &L_5''
\end{matrix}$$
The column $P_7$ gets out of the base and the column $P_6$ gets in.

$L_4'''=L_4''/2$, $L_1'''=L_1''+3L_4'''$, $L_2'''=L_2''-10L_4'''$, $L_3'''=L_3''-L_4'''$

So the next tableau is the following (Since there is no more column in the base with the coeffient  $M$ ($P_7$) you don't have to fill this column):
$$\begin{matrix}
B   & c_B & b & P_1 & P_2 & P_3 & P_4 & P_5 & P_6 & P_7 & \Theta=\frac{b}{P_6} \\ 
P_1 & 100   &25&  1 & 1/2  & 0   & -1/20 & 0   & 0 &    &   50&L_1'''\\ 
P_5 & 0   &350&0   &0   & 0   & -1/2 & 1   &0  &    &   -      &L_2'''\\ 
P_3 & 400 & 45& 0   & 1/2   &  1  & 1/20   & 0   &  0  &    &   90      &L_3'''\\ 
P_6 & 0   & 5&0   & 1/2   & 0   &-1/20   & 0   & 1  &    &   5/2      &L_4'''\\
    & z   & 2500+45 \cdot 400  &  0   &  -50   &  0   &15   &0     &0    &     &         &L_5'''
\end{matrix}$$

Now at the last line you have a negative element. You apply one more time the Simplex method so that you have only elements $\geq 0$.

$L_4''''=2L_4'''$, $L_1''''=L_1'''-\frac{1}{2}L_4''''$, $L_2''''=L_2'''$, $L_3''''=L_3'''-\frac{1}{2}L_4''''$

The last tableau is:

$$\begin{matrix}
B   & c_B & b & P_1 & P_2 & P_3 & P_4 & P_5 & P_6 & P_7 & \Theta=\frac{b}{P_6} \\ 
P_1 & 100   &20&  1 & 0  & 0   & 0 & 0   & -1 &    &   &L_1''''\\ 
P_5 & 0   &350&0   &0   & 0   & -1/2 & 1   &0  &    &         &L_2''''\\ 
P_3 & 400 & 40& 0   & 0   &  1  & 1/10   & 0   &  -1  &    &         &L_3''''\\ 
P_2 & 300   & 10&0   & 1   & 0   &-1/10   & 0   & 2  &    &         &L_4''''\\
    & z   & 21000  &  0   &  0   &  0   &10   &0     &100    &     &         &L_5''''
\end{matrix}$$

Now we have finished. At the last line all the elements are $\geq 0$, and it is only $=0$ at those columns that are in the base.

So which is now the solution? Which is the maximum? Can you find these?

Comment: can you please mary star continue i try but to check th result with your solution

Comment: i try but i don't know how to multiply by M and add this is my problem so please help me???

Comment: @basharsabeeh I edited my answer.. Can you continue now? Or do you need more help?

Comment: no please can you complete it for me ? i know i tired you but i wont to learn this subject to see how the result will be , by the way i am study master degree in electrical power engineer but i don't have any background on this topic so i am learning from you so please complete it for me i am ask too much but i hope to help me thanks

Comment: please i need your help because this is assignment

Comment: @basharsabeeh I edited my answer...

Comment: can you continue please to check the steps and the value with you until the end ,thanks

Comment: we will continue until which we can get ? i wont to imagine the final of this equation and all these tableau ?

Comment: @basharsabeeh I edited again my answer..

Comment: you mean the max. number at column (b) which is equal to 21000

Comment: or what the max. number you mean ???

Comment: @basharsabeeh Yes, that is correct!!! And which is the solution? For which $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ do you get this max?

Comment: the value X1=20, x2=10,x3=40 is it true ???

Comment: Yes, that's right!!! $\checkmark$

Comment: thanks a lot Mary for your help and i wish to continue to get more knowledge , may mail is basharsabeeh181@yahoo.com